# How to create an hyperlink in tcl tk?

Tags: hyperlink, tcl

Im a using Tcl-Tk 8.6.4 and I am a begginner, I would like to create hyperlinks in my texts.
I am looking for a procedure which could have the url of a website in argument, this url will be displayed in blue and underlined in my text. Of course, by clicking on the url, it will open the website.
I have found the following code, but I am not sure that it will do what I want.

```
proc hyperlink { name args } {
  if { "Underline-Font" ni [ font names ] } {
    font create Underline-Font {*}[ font actual TkDefaultFont ]
    font configure Underline-Font -underline true -size 12
  }
  if { [ dict exists $args -command ] } {
    set command [ dict get $args -command ]
    dict unset args -command
  }
  label $name {*}$args -foreground blue -font Underline-Font
  if { [ info exists command ] } {
    bind $name <Button-1> $command
  }
  return $name
}
```

Anyone can help me?

## Update 2

The thing I want is to display hyperlinks in the text of my window like that:

Further informations are given following those links:

- https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/NumericalInt/Lumped_vs_Distributed_Systems.html
- https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/NumericalInt/NumericalInt_4up.pdf

With the first code shown I am able to display that:
[image]
The codes used are:

- in a procedure to read files I have tags like HTML tags such as

  ```
  "<hypLink>" {
      gets $infile inln
      hyperlink .hl${counter} -command [list eval exec [auto_execok start] "$inln"] -text "$inln"
      pack .hl${counter}
      incr counter
  }
  ```
- in my file I write

  Semi-conductors:

  ```
  <hypLink>
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor 
  <hypLink>
  http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/diode.htm
  ```

What can I do to have what I want?

**Note** The first update have been delated for copyright protection

Comment: Let me know if the edit is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `proc` you found. If you have:

```
hyperlink .hl -command [list puts "clicked"] -text "Click Me"
pack .hl
```

in your code and click on the 'hyperlink', you will get the text `clicked` to stdout.

If you want to open the default browser and go to the url specified by the hyperlink, you would have to change the code to:

```
hyperlink .hl -command [list eval exec [auto_execok start] "http://www.example.com"] -text "Click Me"
pack .hl
```

You can also play around with the proc a bit, maybe changing the font size (from `-size 12`) or change the font itself.

---

Post edit:

You can add the 'hyperlink' to your code by adding the below to the switch in the `dispFile` proc:

```
"<hypLink>" {
    gets $infile inln
    .fr.txt insert end "$inln" "link lk$lkcount"
    .fr.txt insert end "\n" Normal
    .fr.txt tag bind lk$lkcount <1> [list eval exec [auto_execok start] "$inln"]
    incr lkcount
}
```

This should create text similar to the text which open files, but instead of opening files will open the link in the default browser.

Comment: With this solution, am I forced to put the url in the code? Because I don't want to. I need to have a "general" procedure which can be called using the url.

Comment: @PiXieBulles Well, while you need _something_ in the code to let the click handler know where to go, it doesn't have to be the URL itself. I'd recommend making the callback be a procedure, and in there you can do anything (well, anything you want and that makes sense) to work out what the URL is. Hard to give better advice without a more specific example.

Comment: I understand what you say @Donal. But I am continuing a program began by another person, I have to use his previous version and add the possibily to have links which can be followed. The program create a window where there are tutorials and tests (accessible via a menu) for students. I want to put some web references to improve the tutorials contents. So, I have several links regarding several topics displayed on different "pages" of the menu. That's all I want to do. Is it a satisfactory example?

Comment: @PiXieBulles What kind of solution are you looking for? I get what you are doing, but I don't know how you are doing it, nor what you believe is the best way for you to do it. I have an idea of how the data structure could be, but I have no idea if that is what you have in front of you. If your description is anything long (with or without code), can you can edit it in the question for readability and leave a comment here to notify of such edit?

Comment: @Jerry, do you want me to put my entire project here?

Comment: @PiXieBulles An example of how it is would be nice, or if you have the project on git or equivalent.

Comment: @Jerry What is the utility of the line `pack .hl` ? Isn't it better to destroy it?

Comment: @PiXieBulles Ok, I see the code now. `pack .hl` will place the widget in the window. If you destroy it, well, you are basically not putting it in the window.

Comment: @PiXieBulles Ok, I added a part to my answer. Can you try it out?

Comment: @PiXieBulles Awesome! :D